# AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'merge_environment_settings'

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, indexing

I have this script that I use to connect to an ElasticSearch cluster on AWS to create some indexes:

```
session = boto3.Session(region_name=os.environ['REGION'])
credentials = session.get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                   credentials.secret_key,
                   session.region_name, 'es',
                   session_token=credentials.token)

es_client = Elasticsearch(
                endpoint_es,
                http_auth=awsauth,
                use_ssl=False,
                verify_certs=False,
                connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)

# Create indexes for delete test
es_client.indices.create(index='sample-index')
```

When I run this script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_update_02.py", line 58, in test_update_02
    es_client.indices.create(index='sample-index')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 91, in create
    params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 72, in perform_request
    settings = self.session.merge_environment_settings(prepared_request.url, {}, None, None, None)
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'merge_environment_settings'
```

Here is the file where there is a problem (line 72 ) : 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py

I don't understand why I get this error. any clues?